# Using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *ptr=(int*)(&a+1);
    printf("%d %d\n",*(a+1),*(ptr-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2,5
```

I could not understand how the `*(ptr-1)` evaluated to 5 (correct output). But when I manually 
did it was 1. My understanding is `*(ptr-1)` will get evaluated to `*(&a+1-1)` which would be 
`*(&a)` which is 1.

Please help me to understand this concept.

Comment: `(&a + 1) != (&a[0] + 1)`

Comment: &a has type pointer to array of 5 ints, not pointer to int. Your cast here is hiding your mistake.

Comment: Why do you want to point to  the address of an address?

Comment: What is 'yashwant kanetkar'?  How is it relevant to the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int *ptr=(int*)(&a+1);
```

makes `&a + 1` makes `&a + sizeof (a)` as `a` is type of `int [5]` which makes `ptr` to point to actually `a[5]` (invalid/beyond the defined limit)

`(ptr - 1)`  points thus points to `a[4]` and `*(ptr - 1)` will print `5`.

Answer (score 5):

In your `printf`, you are retrieving the value in pos 1 by incrementing the position with `+1` from `0`.

In your second integer, you are retrieving `5` because `&a+1` actually points beyond the array, so when you do `*(ptr-1)`, it returns `5`. If you remove the `-1`, then you get a really weird result (in my case it was `-1078772784`).