# where the size of pointer variable gets stored?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int *ptr=(int*)(&a+1);
printf("%d %d\n",*(a+1),*(ptr-1));
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2 5
```

Here in the statement `*ptr= (int*)(&a+1)` 1 is not added to the `&a`. Actually its like `&a + sizeof(a)`. Now my question is where size of the pointer variable is stored or if it is not stored then how it is calculated. In case of `int, float, char` etc their size is predefined in compiler so  int `*a` is a different case. Is it true that only the adress is stored in a pointer variable nothing else?. where the metadata about pointer variable gets stored?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194388/using-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Due to your variable declaration `int a[5] = ...`, the compiler knows that `a` is of type `int [5]` (hence, `sizeof(a)` would return 20). Since the compiler knows the type of `a`, taking the address of `a` will yield a pointer of the right type. This might be a bit surprising: `&a` does not yield an `int**` but rather a `int (*)[5]` (a pointer to an array of five integers).

So when executing

```
int *ptr=(int*)(&a+1);
```

You take the address of `a`, add one (which, due to the way C/C++ pointer arithmetics work, increases the address referenced by the pointer by `sizeof(a)` bytes) and then cast the result to an int. So at this point, `ptr` points behind the last element of the array (at offset 20).

You then cast the pointer to `int*` and use `*(ptr-1)`, so you dereference the int value at offset 16 - which happens to be where the last array element is.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get stored. The compiler certainly needs to keep track of this when it compiles the code, but after that, it is basically just hard-coded into the generated instructions.

Answer (score 0):

&a is of type `int (*)[5]`, i.e., &a is a pointer to an *array*, NOT a pointer to int. The compiler knows (obviously) what the array size is, and uses it for pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer has a "double type". On one hand, it's a pointer with its own size (let's say 4 bytes for every pointer on some systems). On the other hand, it's a pointer to something that has a size (apart from `void *`).

Types in general are not directly accessible in C. You can't ask "what is the type of a variable".

But the size is always accessible through `sizeof`. So `int *` itself may use 4 bytes, but the compiler knows that it's pointing to an integer, and it knows the size of the integer.
For `struct xyz *`, the pointer itself may again be 4 bytes, but the compiler knows that it's pointing to a structure, and it knows the size of the structure. What's important is that the pointer has a type beyond "pointer".

So, if you define `struct xyz *ptr`, you can always find out the size of what the pointer is pointing to, by checking `sizeof(*ptr)`. You can do that even if `ptr` is not initialised.

The only thing you can't do is check `sizeof(*ptr)` when `ptr` is defined `void *`.

In terms of "metadata", it's all in the type of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is only a memory address, there is no metadata. Adding N to pointer of type T* results in adding N*sizeof(T) to the address value. Compiler knows size of every type during compilation, nothing is stored.

- `a+1` points to the second `int` in a, because it treats `a` as `int*` i.e. the pointer to the first element, i.e. sizeof(int) is added to the memory address
- `&a+1` points to the “second int[5] array”, i.e. sizeof(int[5]) is added to the memory address
- `ptr-1` points to an `int` right before the first element of the “second array”, i.e. the last element of a.